# How do i create a timer in Outsystem?

Tags: timer, outsystems

I am unfamiliar with Outsystem as I was very recently and I want to create a basic timer that counts up. The problem is that i'm not sure what to call to allow the program to execute 1 second in real time. I am planning to use a for or if-else loop to create a basic timer for my program.

Comment: Would that timer just be something to show elapsed seconds in the UI?

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in function in Outsystems where you can add seconds, AddSeconds().

See this documentation: https://success.outsystems.com/Documentation/10/Reference/Logic/Built-in_Functions/Date_and_Time_Built-in_Functions

With using local variables and Ajax Refresh you will come far by creating a timer.